# dummy data not being displayed in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular, and did the codeschool course + the angular video from railscasts.

so this is my controller in the html file

```
  <div ng-controller="ProviderDataCtrl">
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
     {{entry.name}}
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

and this is the javascript file holding the controller

```
(function(){

  app.controller('ProviderDataCtrl',function($scope){


$scope.entries = [

{name:"test"}
{name:"test2"}
{name:"test3"}
]

}]);

})();
```

for some reason in my html file, it just shows as {{entry.name}} and only 1 of it.

I cant seem to figure out the problem. Did i define the controller wrong in the js file??

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a plunker? it would be easier for us to help you.

Comment: did you set ngApp in your html and/or are you getting errors on your console?

Comment: @PatrickEvans i defined a ng-app, its my in application.html, so angular is always running no matter what

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kDWqECtrZ4ct4KR4cuU7?p=preview

Comment: you have syntax errors, you do not have commas seperating your array elements, `{name:"test"},{name:"test2"},{name:"test3"}` and an extra `]`, also you are not defining `app` anywhere

Comment: ok i got it to work, I'm just testing around because my angular is actually integrated into my rails app. I'm looking at my coworkers code and he defines in the main.js file. My controller is in a subdirectory under /javascripts/angular/controller
does this subdirectory affect this?

Answer (score 0):

`app` is undefined

First define your angular `app` before using it

`var app = angular.module('test',[]);`

**[Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyxlkmtXrpgc7GZb1pV5?p=preview)**